# WCF security exception

Tags: c#, wcf

i have a console application that is used to launch (open) my wcf services
i have a web application that uses these services.
how can i implement transport level security with authentication?

i have this till now:
service:

```
 WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
 ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(Type.GetType(MyClass);       
 svh.AddServiceEndpoint(IMyClass, binding, "https://localhost:9090/ServiceTest");                       
 ServiceMetadataBehavior sb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
 sb.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
 sb.HttpsGetUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:9090/ServiceTest");
 svh.Description.Behaviors.Add(sb);
 svh.Open();
```

Client:

```
 WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
 EndpointIdentity endpointIdentity = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("localhost");
 EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://localhost:9090/ServiceTest"), endpointIdentity, new AddressHeaderCollection());    
 ChannelFactory<T> engineFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, endPoint);
 T MyService = engineFactory.CreateChannel();
```

i first launch the console application... and all my services are open.
but when i call a method in the service from the webapplication i get an exception saying:

```
 An error occurred while making the HTTP request to 
 https://localhost:9090/ServiceTest. This could be due to the fact that the
 server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This 
 could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the 
 server.
```

when i googled... i found that i need to set ssl certificates on iis... but my services are hosted on a console application... then how can i set these certificates? moreover how can i set a username and password for to allow usage of the service?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFSSL.aspx).

You need to setup your certificate.

Comment: this one can help too !https://notgartner.wordpress.com/2007/09/06/using-certificate-based-authentication-and-protection-with-windows-communication-foundation-wcf/

Answer (score 0):

+1 on the @Aliostad answer.

Another option for you is to use a different binding if you can. You can get Transport security by default with a [NetTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx) for example, without having to setup certificates. This approach would be much less work.